# Different builds or configuration for each app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect

I am building an online shopping app that I want to launch in the UK and US store territories. I was wondering is there any way I can provide different builds or different configuration for each store? The idea is that the app needs to send a string value key (that should be different depending from which store the app was downloaded) in the web requests to the server so the server knows what data to return to the app user (for UK and US users the result data is different).

Other solution I was thinking was to give user an option to select which store he wants to use. Any other ides, recommendation? Please suggest.

Comment: Try NSLocalizedString for the this purpose. You can learn on this using this tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: localisation is a very well understood concept. You need to do some research

Answer (score 0):

Question: can a user located in the UK shop the US store?

"Yes" scenario:

- You may need two different apps or a selection inside the app;
- Depending on this you select which resource to use as strings file for the web requests.

"No" scenario:

- Take the location from the IP or user account;
- With the info you select which resource to use as strings file for the web requests.

For the strings file using check the tutorial @borncrazy suggested (http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios).

Comment: Thanks for the answers Fábio and @borncrazy. I am not sure how can localisation help me to distinguish if the app was downloaded in the UK store or US store?  As I know, localisation is affected by Language settings on the device, or am I wrong? So I was thinking maybe to make my decision based on the currentLocale from NSLocale.

Comment: NSLocale and localisation work together. You have multiple string files (for instance, as it can be images or any other kind of resources), each for each locale, and in run time you can get the one for the device locale or for one locale that you choose.

Comment: However I'd like you to comment my question. At least we could then focus in one scenario.

Comment: I am not sure do I follow you. For example. A user device Language is set to German, but Region Format set to United Kingdom. The app has 2 Localizations - English en_GB and German de_DE. If I try to use NSLocalizedString to get string value from Localizable.strings or any custom value from Info.plist (using NSBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey) I will always get German.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify the origin of this problem in your app. Why do you need to communicate differently with the server? Can you edit your question? Maybe that's a requirement for your but maybe we are going for the long path around what can be a simple problem.

Comment: Then I think the scenario where you need two different apps is the best one for you. As you said: the string value "should be different depending from which store the app was downloaded". If you really have a requirement on the store you need two apps.